# Is it faster to store window.location.href in a const to do several comparisons or check it directly?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is it faster to store the window.location.href in a const to check if contains several strings,

```
   const fullUrl = window.location.href;

 function checkUrlContains() {
   return fullUrl.indexOf("string1") > 1 || fullUrl.indexOf("string2") > 1  || fullUrl.indexOf("string3") > 1 || fullUrl.indexOf("string4") > 1
 }
```

or to check directly the window.location.href?

```
     function checkUrlContains() {
   return window.location.href.indexOf("string1") > 1 || window.location.href.indexOf("string2") > 1  || window.location.href.indexOf("string3") > 1 ...
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: It would only be worth doing if you're performing thousands and thousands of tests on the href value, and in that case it'd be a much better idea to figure out how to stop doing that.

Comment: Keep in mind that IF it would be faster or slower we'd just be talking about micro/milliseconds

Comment: @Pointy would it save anything?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I doubt it, though it's *possible* that it'd shave a microsecond off of some operation or another. Compared to the inherent uncertainty of network behavior and multi-tasking on a modern computer or phone, I'd argue that such a "savings" would be absolutely impossible to notice.

Comment: @Pointy I don't know if I did this right, but I made a jsperf test. https://jsperf.com/location-const-test/1

Comment: @evolutionxbox that jsperf is about everything that's wrong with sterile microbenchmarks put into a single page. Towards the actual question, "premature optimization is the root of all evil", and that applies very much here.

Comment: @ASDFGerte but the numbers are so pretty

Comment: Don't worry about such things anymore.  *"At a billion operations per second, nobody can hear you scream ..."*  The days when this sort of thing was a practical and necessary consideration are, thankfully, long gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the "thin" books are the best ones.  Such as, *The Elements of Programming Style.*  In which you will read:

```
"Don't 'diddle' code to make it faster -- find a better algorithm."
```

But also:  "don't assume that an algorithm is 'too slow' unless you can prove by actual profiling measures *that* it is too slow and *where* it is.  In your case, that source-code change probably won't make any measurable difference in performance, but it just might make your code harder to "instantly understand" by the next programmer who follows in your footsteps.  The only time (these days) when you should seriously be concerned about such things is when profiling results *prove* that this-or-that is a true "hot spot."  Otherwise, just write code as clearly and obviously as you can, and of course be very certain that it works!

Comment: +1.  And one minor addition -- If the item will be referenced in code a hundred times, it may be better to have a short const that shrinks the source code.  Programmer time and effort is important.  And, if it shows up 100 times, the reader will quickly learn the shorthand and not be checking that the long version is actually the same as the other 99.

Comment: My Rule Of Thumb -- If a quick guess does not say "this change will improve the code (speed/space/whatever) by 10% or more; put it aside and look for some other improvements."  (This one is _far_ less than 10%.)